# Solving incompatible dtype warning for pandas DataFrame when setting new column iteratively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Setting the value of a new dataframe column:

```
df.loc[df["Measure] == metric.label, "source_data_url"] = metric.source_data_url
```

now (as of Pandas version 2.1.0) gives a warning,

```
FutureWarning:
Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise in a future error of pandas. Value '       metric_3' has dtype incompatible with float64, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype
 first.
```

The [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.1.0.html#deprecated-silent-upcasting-in-setitem-like-series-operations) discusses how the problem can be solved for a Series but it is not clear how to do this iteratively (the line above is called in a loop over metrics and it's the final metric that gives the warning) when assigning a new DataFrame column. How can this be done?

Comment: Will appending `.astype('object')` to each series in the loop work for you?

Comment: Interesting that despite of the documentation show the "previous behavior" and the "new behavior", I couldn't see any difference! (only the warning!)

Comment: This is a completely counter-intuitive warning and it should be fixed at upstream pandas as at least non-useful information to the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. My intuition of this is that when you are setting value for the first time to the column `source_data_url`, the column does not yet exists, so pandas creates a column `source_data_url` and assigns value `NaN` to all of its elements. This makes Pandas think that the column's `dtype` is `float64`. Then it raises this warning.

My solution was to create the column with some default value, e.g. empty string, before adding values to it:

`df["source_data_url"] = ""`

or `None` seems also to work:

`df["source_data_url"] = None`

Comment: This is why it's a great idea to use the newer "nullable" dtypes, which can accommodate null values without conversion to float or falling back to Python object.

Comment: This worked for me and it was a helpful explanation. Thank you!

Comment: I have a dataset I am processing so the value already exists and its still giving the warning. I have removed every row apart form one so there is no concern about pandas finding mixed data types in the column data and getting confused. Everything is a string and its still complaining.

Comment: This is a completely counter-intuitive warning and it should be fixed at upstream pandas as at least non-useful information to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Since Pandas 2.1.0 setitem-like operations on Series (or DataFrame columns) which silently upcast the dtype are deprecated and show a warning.

In a future version, these will raise an error and you should cast to a common dtype first.

**Previous behavior:**

```
In [1]: ser = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])

In [2]: ser
Out[2]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64

In [3]: ser[0] = 'not an int64'

In [4]: ser
Out[4]:
0    not an int64
1               2
2               3
dtype: object
```

**New behavior:**

```
In [1]: ser = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])

In [2]: ser
Out[2]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64

In [3]: ser[0] = 'not an int64'
FutureWarning:
  Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise an error in a future version of pandas.
  Value 'not an int64' has dtype incompatible with int64, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.

In [4]: ser
Out[4]:
0    not an int64
1               2
2               3
dtype: object
```

To **retain the current behaviour**, you could cast ser to object dtype first:

```
In [21]: ser = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])

In [22]: ser = ser.astype('object')

In [23]: ser[0] = 'not an int64'

In [24]: ser
Out[24]: 
0    not an int64
1               2
2               3
dtype: object
```

Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.1.0.html#deprecated-silent-upcasting-in-setitem-like-series-operations

Comment: How do I cast a dtype that could be a float or a null, or a boolean or a null. Etc?

Comment: My first approach would be to check the dtype of the new data (e.g. with `type(xyz)` and then cast that type to the series.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was casting the main `Series`/`DataFrame` data to `object` before doing the operations on it; do the operations, then cast it back to the appropriate type.

```
df = df.astype(object)
# [...] Do the operation here
df = df.astype(<type>)
```

I thought simply casting the result of the operation to the appropriate type would solve the problem but it didn't.